# Is there a data structure that can potentially represent all other data structures?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, graph-theory

I'd like to know whether it's conceivable to have a data structure that can represent all forms of data structures.

I am particularly interested in this from the prospect that if there is such a thing, it would be possible to make a database that could universally represent different architectures, and therefore rendering a universal, low-level query language.

For instance, maps are quite versatile and can represent trees of many types, graphs can represent relations and paths etc. However I'm aware that there are weird axioms like the one that says that: "no set can contain all sets", so with this reservation in mind, what is there?

Comment: When commenting or explaining, please stay civil!

Comment: Just about any unbounded data structure, including plain text, can represent any/all other data structures if there are no constraints on how to interpret its contents.

Comment: @Matt-Timmermans Yes that's obvious enough. But I'm asking about a disciplined data structure that's like a map or a graph. Although you could arguably state that a string is a vector, so maybe you're right.

Comment: @Matt-Timmermans Additionally, I'd like to underline my point: is there in potential a low-level query language/form that can answer all other data structures?

Comment: What does it mean "can answer all other data structures"? How would you test and decide whether a data structure would fulfil or fail that requirement? The internet seems a great data structure. Also my laptop and smartphone seem to be doing fine in managing data.

Comment: @trincot Yes, but every one of your "data structures" is queried in wildly different ways, and not just because of choice, but because of the peculiar constraints various data structures impose on themselves. My point in example is a dynamic map, which can be treated equally well as a tree, a vector as a map, and a list as a stack (using clojure terminology). My question is, is there a data structure that could support all of these different approaches to querying? So you see, could you structure an immutable map in a way that it could viably represent a graph with relations?

Comment: So again, how would you judge a data structure? Do you have tests that must pass? What about a heap, a red black tree, a bit map, a B+ tree, a circular doubly linked list, a skip list, a suffix tree, a segment tree, a trie, a binomial heap,... the number of data structures is really without end, as new ones are invented continually. So "all other data structures" is really a too broad question.

Comment: Given any Turing-complete query language, you can represent whatever data structure you like in its input, no matter what format of input that is, and query it however you want... We could probably go back and forth on this a few times, but the bottom line is that one data structure is chosen over another, not because of what you can do with it, but because of what you can do simply and/or efficiently.  Given that, then *of course* there is no universal data structure.

Comment: So would stating that: "The concept of data structures is infinite, and therefore all methods of querying are infinite" be correct? Is there a proof of that? I'd assume that something of the sort would have been stated by someone? Forgive me if I ramble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept doesn't really make sense. It's akin to asking: *Is there a universal furniture that can replace all others?* You can use a cube as a shelf, but not a good one. You can use a cube as a chair, but not a good one. A table, maybe even bed. But the individual furnitures are geared towards a specific task. The universal one is rubbish at any specific task.

Similarly, even if you find a data structure that can do everything, it'll likely be extremely bad at most things that have specialised data structures. For example: A graph would come closest to being able to represent simple data structures like arrays, sets, dictionaries, but all would require specific algorithms spun around it. How would you make a hashmap? The features of the hashmap would be in the implementation of the hash function. What about the array? A general purpose graph probably will lack the performance of a raw array.

A universal data structure can, by definition, not provide specialised operations. And it wont be optimised for the purpose you would intend to use it for.